# Direction vectors are linearly dependent, if $D_vf(x)=D_wf(x)=0$ with $\operatorname{grad} f(x)\neq 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous differentiable and $x \in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\operatorname{grad} f(x) \neq 0$. Let $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be direction vectors.
>
> If $D_v f(x) = D_w f(x)=0$ then are $v$ and $w$ linearly dependent.

For my proof I use the following theorem:

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be open and $f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous differentiable. Then it holds for $x \in U$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ with $\|v\| = 1$ that $D_v f(x) = \langle v, \operatorname{grad} f(x) \rangle$.

Proof:

With the theorem above and the assumption, we know that 
$$
    \langle v, \operatorname{grad} f(x) \rangle
  = \langle w, \operatorname{grad} f(x) \rangle.
$$
It holds that 
\begin{align*}
     \langle v, \operatorname{grad} f(x) \rangle
  &\overset{\phantom{D_vf(x)=D_wf(x)}}{=}
     \sum_{i=1}^2 v_i \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}
   =   v_1 \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}
     + v_2 \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \\
  &\overset{D_vf(x)=D_wf(x)}{=}
     \sum_{i=1}^2 w_i \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}
   =   w_1 \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}
     + w_2 \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}
   = 0
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
      &\,
      v_1 \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}
    + v_2 \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}
  =   w_1 \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}
    + w_2 \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \\
  \iff&\,
      (v_1-w_1) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}
    + (v_2-w_2) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}
  = 0
\end{align*}

Since $\operatorname{grad} f(x) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_w}\right) \neq 0$ this is a non trivial linear combination of $0$.

Hence $v$ and $w$ are linearly dependent.

Is this proof correct?
I am actually not sure if I used the correct scalar product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(v_1-w_1)\,f_1^{(1)}+(v_2-w_2)\,f^{(2)}$ is not a linear combination of the vectors $v$ and $w$, nor does it imply that they are linearly dependent. E.g., if $\nabla f=(1,1)$, then this quantity vanishes for $v=(1,0)$ and $w=(0,1)$.

Comment: @amd Thanks for pointing that out. Is the approach not suitable in general? How can I proof this instead?

Comment: Both $v$ and $w$ satisfy a particular homogeneous linear equation. What can you say about that equation’s solution space?

Comment: @amd I looked into my lecture notes, but I did not find anything about a homogeneous linear equation, which $v$ and $w$ satisfy. Do you have a source on this topic? Or do you just mean the quoted theorem, which gives: $\begin{pmatrix} v_1& v_2\\ w_1&w_2\end{pmatrix}\cdot\operatorname{grad}f(x)=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For given $x$ in the domain of $f$ the  derivative $df(x)$ (also denoted by $f'(x)$, or similar) is a linear map acting as
$$df(x):\quad {\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R},\qquad X\mapsto\langle\nabla f(x),X\rangle\ ,$$
whereby $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the standard scalar product in ${\mathbb R}^2$, as in the question.
Since $\nabla f(x)\ne0$ by assumption this map has rank $1$; hence its kernel $K$ has dimension $2-1=1$. We are told that both $v$ and $w$ are in $K$; therefore $v$ and $w$ have to be linearly dependent.

Note that this argument does not work for an $f:\>{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$ with $n>2$.

Comment: How do we get $df(x).X=\langle\nabla f(x), X\rangle$ and how is $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ defined here? Standard scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^2$?